Outlook New Web Based Add-ins: How to retrieve original email/item ID staying on the reply/forward composing tab?
I am building an outlook web based addin.
Suppose I setup OnMessageCompose event which will trigger messageCompose() function when reply/reply all/forward button will be clicked.
Now

select an email from inbox and click on reply/reply all/ forward.
It will open the compose window.
Also it will catch the event of OnMessageCompose.
In the messageCompose function I need the item ID of the selected email/original email not the currently replying email.

How can I get the itemID for the original email to which I am replying? Are there any properties, or methods of OfficeJS or Microsoft Graph API? Or is there any tricks to achieve this?
I found **conversationId **to retrive the the mail chain, but I want specifically that one email which i am replying to, not the whole email thread.
Also the same Question(Q. link) was asked for VSTO but my addin is outlook web based addin.

If I read your question correctly, this new capability announced at Build 2024 may be what you are looking for.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
